# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

GsranjifyQuickzLook.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import loopSkus from './stranify';

class GsranjifyQuickzLook extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        loopSkus(this.props.data)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   const data = get(state, 'navigation.breadcrumbs');
   return { data };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GsranjifyQuickzLook);
```

stranify.js

```
export const loopSkus = (productDataForSk) => {
  return productDataForSku.skus.map(sku => `{
    "id": "${get(sku, 'id')}",
    "title": "${get(productDataForSku, 'name')}",
    "brand": "${get(productDataForSku, 'linkedData.brand', '')}",
   }`);
};
```

above I am trying to add a React map component to my project but running into an error. Here  above is my map component so far.

Comment: What sort of error are you encountering? Add it to your question, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

put  -- { } -- brackets . while importing

```
import  loopSkus  from './stranify' .  ---not work

import { loopSkus } from './stranify' .  --- working
```

Answer (score 1):

you have `import loopSkus from './stranify';` in `GsranjifyQuickzLook.js`

that's the `default` import syntax. in `./stranify`, you're exporting as a named export. Either add `export default loopSkus` to `./stranify` or import as `import { loopSkus } from './stranify';`